# Integrating dropzone.js with Shopify

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, shopify, dropzone.js

I'm trying to integrate dropzone.js into my Shopify theme. Shopify allows file-uploads to be attached to line-items using `form action="cart/add"`

Shopify looks for `name="properties[SOMETHING]" id="SOMETHING"` in the input field and attaches it as an attribute in the cart.

A no-frills working example of this simple code in my theme is found here: http://squishpress.com/products/10-stickers

Problems begin when I start implementing Dropzone.js // I've followed enyo's tutorial for using an existing form on GitHub. (no link because I can only post 2 links per post)

Here is my test page with dropzone.js installed: http://squishpress.com/products/10-x-18

My config file looks like:

```
<script>

Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

// The configuration we've talked about above
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: false,
addRemoveLinks: true,
parallelUploads: 1,
maxFiles: 1,

// The setting up of the dropzone
init: function() {
var myDropzone = this;

// First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
this.element.querySelector("input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});

// Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
// of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
  // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
  // Hide the success button or the complete form.
});
this.on("success", function(files, response) {
  // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
  // Redirect user or notify of success.
  $('#my-awesome-dropzone').submit();
});
this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
  // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
  // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
});
this.on("processing", function() {
this.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
});
}

}
```

I've modified my dropzone.js library (I know, it's not good to leave it this way-- for now it's just a test) to add the necessary attributes to the file input here (line 791):

```
      _this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("name", "properties[Front Image]");
      _this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("id", "Front Image");
```

Not sure why, but my files never make it to the cart when submit button is pressed.

The properties attributes are returned null, and I have no way to test if the files were uploaded to the cart/add file on the shopify server.

Hoping someone can help shed some light on how dropzone is handling the files that are dropped in the form, what it does with the arrays it builds, and how it is sending those files once I press submit.

Can anyone help?

Alternatively, I could look at a different library to use, but this seems really close to what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the dropzone.js see if they're the same as your other .js files.

Comment: Checked, they are all set to 755.